# How to use observables in F#

Tags: forms, user-interface, merge, f#, observable

I am trying to create a graphical application in F# using observables. The code I have so far is:

```
open System.Windows.Forms
let form = new Form(Text="Test", TopMost=true)

let buttonNum0 = new Button(Text="1");
let buttonNum1 = new Button(Text="2", Top=20);
let buttonNum2 = new Button(Text="3", Top=40);
let buttonNum3 = new Button(Text="4", Top=60);

form.Controls.AddRange [| buttonNum0 ; buttonNum1; buttonNum2; buttonNum3 ; |]
let rec loop observable list = async{
            printList list

(Async.Await)
    let! somethingObservable = Async.AwaitObservable(observable) 

    match somethingObservable with
    | 0     -> return! loop observable ("0"::list)
    | 1     -> return! loop observable ("1"::list)
    | 2     -> return! loop observable ("2"::list)
    | 3     -> return! loop observable ("3"::list)
    | _     -> return! loop observable ("?"::list)
}
module GUIInterface = 
    //Here we define what we will be observing (clicks)
    let observables =
        Observable.merge 
        <| Observable.map (fun _-> 0) GUI.buttonNum0.Click 
        <| Observable.map (fun _-> 1) GUI.buttonNum1.Click              
        <| Observable.map (fun _-> 2) GUI.buttonNum2.Click 
        <| Observable.map (fun _-> 3) GUI.buttonNum3.Click

Async.StartImmediate(loop GUIInterface.observables []) ; System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(GUI.form)
```

I have tried using more or less Observables and when I use only two of them (for examle 0 and 1) then it is working fine. Can Observable.merge only use 2 Obsevables? Is there a better way to do this or how can I use several observables?

With my mediocre searching skills I've searched the internet for some tutorials and references, that in an easy way explains the concept of observables, reactional functional programming, .net and WinForms. If you've got any links to good sites I'd gladly have them. (Tried msdn (maybe not the right part of it?) and http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/concurrency-reactive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why your code wouldn't work (my guess is that it's not parsing your syntax quite how you're expecting--use parentheses rather than backpipes to make order of ops more explicit), but this works in my code:

```
let btns = [GUI.buttonNum0; GUI.buttonNum1; GUI.buttonNum2; GUI.buttonNum3]
let observables = btns |> List.mapi(fun i btn -> Observable.map (fun _ -> i) btn.Click)
Observable.Merge observables
```

Comment: You are using `Observable` static class from RX.NET, whose `Merge` method has multiple overloads, including one that takes a sequence of observables, which is what you use. But OP uses `Observable` module from FSharp.Control, whose `merge` function takes two observables, not a sequence. To this end, I don't understand how the OP's code even compiles.

Comment: Would RX.net be a better choice? I'd like to learn how to use F# GUI through Windows Forms, so I decided to make a simple calculator. Do you know of any site that would help me aquire the knowledge I need?

Comment: Found https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx so will try to learn in and use it instead. Thanks for the answer, hopefully it will work as soon as I use the same Observable.Merge as you do.

Comment: @SebastianLindgren Both libraries are just that--libraries. They both operate on the same `IObservable` interface. So feel free to mix and match whichever functions work best for your use case.

Comment: @SebastianLindgren You can also look into the MVC framework for WPF here https://github.com/dmitry-a-morozov/fsharp-wpf-mvc-series/wiki. I personally just have never liked data binding and wouldn't use it for a real project, but if you want to see some neat F# tricks for building GUIs, it's a good start (steep learning curve though).  I think there's even a calculator example.

Answer (score 2):

After developing my skills some more I came up with another solution to this problem. When using FSharp.Control you can merge two observables to one and then repeat this process. Therefor the solution I came up with used that. By using recursion you can loop through the observables, which I decided to put in a list, and first put the first two together, then the sum with the next and so on.

Alternative Answer:

```
let obsList = [ for x in 0..80 ->  (Observable.map (fun _-> x) ((Array.get(gameButtons)(x)).Click)) ]

let rec obsMerger obsList =
        match obsList with
        | x1::[] -> x1
        | x1::xs -> Observable.merge x1 (obsMerger xs)
        | [] -> failwith "No Observables"
```